# Firestore returning a positive hit when there isn't one

Tags: android, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I am running a query on my data in Firestore however, i am expecting the query to be null, however the code in Kotlin seems to be entering into the !=null statement.

in the link https://ibb.co/N2nbX1s you can see that firestore is not pulling data, yet it does enter into the !=null. why would the code do this?

I am really confused because in all other instances in my app the same query works perfectly. my code below as well.

```
docref = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("winning_bid").document(dealid)

    docref.get().addOnSuccessListener { value ->

        if (value != null) {

            new_lead.visibility = View.GONE
            buyerbid_confirmlead.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            buyerbid_selectleading.visibility = View.VISIBLE

            Log.d("firestoreorigdeal",dealid)

            Log.d("Firestoredeal","${value.data}")


            Log.d("firestore2", "second check")

        } else {


            new_lead.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            buyerbid_confirmlead.visibility = View.GONE
            buyerbid_selectleading.visibility = View.GONE


            Log.d("firestore3", "third check")
            Log.d("Firestore_error", "No Data")

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`value` will never be null.  The returned Task will always yield a DocumentSnapshot object, even if the document doesn't exist.  You can check the snapshot to see if it contains data by using its [exists()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentSnapshot.html#exists()) method.  And, according to the API documentation, [getData()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentSnapshot.html#getData()) will return null if the document doesn't exist, which is what you're seeing here.

Comment: Hi Doug, thanks so much for the clarification. i have been playing around with scenario's endlessly. did not know that is will never be null and now that i have tried it with the .exists() it works as expected!